# How to check if stdin is closed?

Tags: c, stdin, fgets, fcntl

I am writing a program which currently gets continuous input from stdin and does something with it until stdin is closed.

```
fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
while(fcntl(fileno(stdin), F_GETFD) != -1 || errno != EBADF){
    /*
    some code
    */
    fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
}
```

Currently to test out if this is a valid way of checking if stdin is closed the

```
some code
```

is set to just print buffer continuously. However when I try to close stdin with Ctrl +D the program keeps printing whatever it had in buffer indefinitely. Why is that?

Comment: When stdin is closed, `fgets()` will return `NULL` to indicate EOF.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: you should check `ferror(stdin)` to verify why `fgets` returned `NULL`.

Comment: And generally speaking, *always* check the return value of any input function.

Comment: Pressing Control-D does not close the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no portable way to detect that a `FILE *` has been closed, even for predefined streams such as `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr`. Testing the system handle `fileno(stdin)` is not portable and accessing the handle of a stream has undefined behavior if the stream has been closed with `fclose()`.

You seem to make a confusion between closing a stream, which is performed by `fclose()`, and reaching the end of file, which is detected by testing the return value of `fgets()` and other functions reading from a stream.

Here is a modified version:

```
while (fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)) {
    /*
    some code handling the input received in buffer.
    */
}
```

Comment: *You seem to make a confusion between closing a stream, which is performed by fclose(), and reaching the end of file* Indeed.  If `stdin` has been redirected from a file, for example, it won't ever be "closed" unless the process itself closes it, so testing if `stdin` has been closed is not in general useful.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: good point: ^D does not actually close the file handle, it causes `read` to return immediately with the number of bytes buffered so far, which is `0` at the beginning of line. The stream library interprets that as an end of file.

Comment: You can also check with `!feof(stdin)`.

Comment: @foxesque: be very wary of `feof(stdin)`: it may be set by a read operation that failed, but you cannot predict this operation failure by checking `feof()` before calling it.  Hence the correct way to stop at end of file is to check the return value of `fgets()`, and then possibly use `feof()` or `ferror()` to try and distinguish end of file from a read error condition.